# I am getting app crash in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting app crash in xcode with error

"**Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UIApplication.m:3401**"

How to resolve this error?

Comment: @raurora Please *vote to close* rather than just commenting.

Comment: @Droppy Sure thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line from appdelegate.m file in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
```

By removing this line code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

You are using Old version. you still continue than:

```
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
```

You should instead replace it with:

```
[window setRootViewController:viewController];
```